# Need help going from 400 amp panel to a 200 amp

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

I want to run 3/0 aluminum wire 135 feet to my 200 amp panel from my 400 amp main. Is this wire sufficient and will it pull thru 2 1/2" conduit (mine is 3” choked down to 2 1/2" on the last ten feet on each end).

Comment: I think you mean a 400 amp main instead of a 4000 amp main.

Comment: @JACK you can just make the edit yourself...

Comment: @FreeMan  I know  but I hate to just change a  number on a post.

Comment: Don't you mean 3/0 copper?  For 200A, you need 250 kcmil aluminum (or 3/0 copper if cost is no object). You would need to breaker 3/0 Al at 150A.

Answer (score 5):

3/0 AL is only good for 155A assuming 75°C terminals, so, no. You can't use the 90°C column because the terminals are not rated for that. It's only of use in derating. And it's still not 200A for 3/0 AL. 200A on 3/0 would require copper, and would be a huge waste of money.

You need 250MCM, minimum, and a 2 AWG grounding wire unless your conduit is metallic.

Which will fit in 2-1/2" conduit comfortably for XHHW or THWN insulation types.

Comment: ... and we want those wires to be comfortable.

Comment: @JACK more a case that we want the wires to be DIY-pullable...

Comment: 40% fill is allowed, but no fun at all to pull, particularly for large stuff. So not getting particularly close to 40% is a good rule for DIY pulling. Depending on conduit type and insulation type this is floating around 32% fill.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  More so with aluminum than copper.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a calculated load requiring 200A you will need 250KCM AL.

If 200A is panel size and not load size then normally you can get by with 180A rated 75°C 4/0 AWG AL since 180A is not a standard breaker size NEC 240.4 would allow using the next larger breaker size, which is 200A.

If using 4/0 AL the minimum size equipment ground would be #4 AL, increasing wire size above the minimum size required would require a larger ground.

If you already have 3/0 AL and replacing it is not an option you could use a 175A breaker in the 400A panel to feed the 200A panel, you will just not have full capacity at the 200A panel.

At 135' you should not experience a significant voltage drop to the panel.

Your conduit is sized adequately.